# Preload Account ID for New Case Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, urlhacking, url

I have custom visualforce page to create a new case and I'd like to have a New Case button on the Acocunt page in the Cases list.
Can I hack the url to push the Account Id into the Account field?
If my list button is URL:

```
/apex/CaseCreateCTM1
```

Can I hack it with something like:

```
/apex/CaseCreateCTM1?Account={!Account.id}
```

Or do I need to add something else?
thanks
Also, there are other things I am doing with this page - pushing users to a second page to add case team members. thanks!

Case controller class:

```
public class CasewithCaseTeamExtension {

private ApexPages.StandardController sc;

public CaseTeamMember CTM {get; set;}
public List<CaseTeamMember> CTMS {get; set;}
public Account ActID {get; set;}     
public String selectedCaseTeamMember {get; set;}   

public User ProxyUser {get; set;}

public string Username {
        get {
            return [
                    select Name
                    from User
                    where Id = :Userinfo.getUserId()
                ].Name;
        }
        set;

}
public String userProfileName1 {
        get {
            return [
                    select Profile.Name
                    from User
                    where Id = :Userinfo.getUserId()
                    ].Profile.Name;
        }
    }


public PageReference Init()
{
 String userProfileName =  [ select Profile.Name
                    from User
                    where Id = :Userinfo.getUserId()
                    ].Profile.Name;

  if (userProfileName.contains('B') )
  {


    PageReference redirecturl = new PageReference('/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Case&retURL=%2F500%2Fo&save_new_url=%2F500%2Fe%3FretURL%3D%252F500%252Fo');
    return redirecturl;
  }

  // Stay on the page
  return null;
}    




public CasewithCaseTeamExtension (ApexPages.StandardController StandardController) {

    //Store a reference to the standard controller
    sc = standardController;

    //create a new sprint instance to collect user input
    CTM = new CaseTeamMember();

    //create a new list to store the sprints added by the user
    CTMS = new List<CaseTeamMember>();

  ActID =  [select id from Account where Id=: (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId'))];
objCase = new Case();
objCase.AccountID=ActID.id;

}    


public PageReference ToPage2() {

    if(ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetURL().ToLowerCase().StartsWith('/apex/CaseCreateCTM1')){

        //Save code

    }
    sc.save();
    return Page.CaseCreateCTM2;

}    
public PageReference SaveCTM() {

    Case Case1 = (Case)sc.GetRecord();
    CaseTeamRole CTRole = [select id from CaseTeamRole where name =:'Sales'];
    CTM.ParentId = Case1.Id;
    CTM.TeamRoleId = CTRole.Id;
    insert CTM;

    CTMS.Add(CTM);
    CTM = new CaseTeamMember();

    return null;

}  

public PageReference SaveAndFinish() {

    Case Case1 = (Case)sc.GetRecord();
    CaseTeamRole CTRole = [select id from CaseTeamRole where name =:'Sales'];
    CTM.ParentId = Case1.Id;
    CTM.TeamRoleId = CTRole.Id;


    CTMS.Add(CTM);
    CTM = new CaseTeamMember();

    PageReference redirecturl = new PageReference('/'+Case1.id);
    return redirecturl;

}    
public PageReference FinishEntry() {
    Case Case1 = (Case)sc.GetRecord();


    PageReference redirecturl = new PageReference('/'+Case1.id);
    return redirecturl;

}


}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CasewithCaseTeamExtension" action="{!Init}" >
    {!userProfileName1}
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="New Case" >
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                                        <apex:commandButton action="{!ToPage2}" value="Continue" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
             <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Case Details">
                 <b> Case Owner:{!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}</b>

                 <apex:inputField  value="{!ObjCase.AccountId}" />  

                 <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Origin}" />
                 <apex:inputField value="{!Case.ContactId}" />


</apex:page>
```

Page truncated for ease.

Comment: I made a lot of changes but the above is the working code - i wonder if there is inefficiency in  this part  -  ActID =  [select id from Account where Id=: (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId'))];
    objCase = new Case();
    objCase.AccountID=ActID.id;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/apex/CaseCreateCTM1?AccountId={!Account.id}
```

Pass Id in url and get id in controller and assign to Case AccountId

Controller

```
public class CaseCreateCTM1Controller
{
   public Case objCase   {get;set;}
   public CaseCreateCTM1Controller()
   {
       objCase = new Case();
       objCase.AccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId')
   }
}
```

And in your vf page

```
<apex:inputField value="{!objCase.AccountId}">
```

---

You can use `{!$CurrentPage.parameters.AccountId}`  since this is lookup field you need to use `<apex:inputField>`

--

### Updates

```
public CasewithCaseTeamExtension (ApexPages.StandardController StandardController) {

    //Store a reference to the standard controller
    sc = standardController;

    //create a new sprint instance to collect user input
    CTM = new CaseTeamMember();

    //grab AccounId and assign to CaseTeamMember.
    CTM.AccounId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId');


    //create a new list to store the sprints added by the user
    CTMS = new List<CaseTeamMember>();

}
```

AND VF page

```
<apex:inputField value="{!CTM.AccountId}">
```

Comment: I already have a controller extension

Comment: @jaw999 are you looking for something else.. I dn't think you will find another except this..

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to push. I will add my code to the question

Comment: getting the  CTM.AccounId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId'); to compile an issue.

Comment: @jaw999 what issue you are getting?

Comment: I used  Case.AccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId'); b/c Case Team Member (ctm) doesn't have an account id field. And for my VF page uses   <apex:inputField value="{!Case.AccountId}"/>  - it all loads but does not prefil

Comment: Updated with code. I am getting the Account Id and can show it on the page, but don't know how to load it into the field

Answer (score 0):

Use

/apex/CaseCreateCTM1?def_account_id={!Account.id}

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass parameter to your VF page in URL, then read this parameter in your controller and populate Account field based on that.